# How to use local dictionary to my app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In My application, how should i find meaning of the word, it should work both online and offline? Please help me out also is there any possiblilite to take local dictionary from iphone?

Sri

Comment: Well, for Android you would call an Intent, this would open another application to get relevant data. Is there something like that for iOS? You could always check into that.

Also, are you look up an infinite possibility of words? If its just a handful, you could just make a local db. If not, your going to want to have a network connection. Unless of course there is an open-source type db you could build into your app. I think that might be huge though.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am currently aware, you aren't able to query the iPhone's built in dictionary.

Even if you could, I am not sure that it contains any definitions. Rather it looks for spelling correction on "close" words.

If you are wanting to replicate storing a dictionary inside your app, like the many dictionary apps currently out there, you would have to store the data in your iPhone app somehow.

[Wikitionary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiktionary) provides free "dumps" of it's data which you could grab, and put into a form that would be usable in your app.

You would need to store the data in some form of plist, an [SQLite](http://www.mobileorchard.com/iphone-sqlite-tutorials-and-libraries/) database or [CoreData](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html).

For taking data from the internet, you would need to look at transferring the data using JSON, XML or PLIST.